# How to detect when an audio device has been unplugged (windows vista) in C#

Tags: c#

Id like to know how to detect when a device has been plugged in,  and unplugged, and then mute / unmute the laptops internal speakers

Comment: Isn't this functionality laptops do out of the box via hardware?

Comment: If by audio device, you mean headphone/microphone in standard 1/8 inch jack, you are SOL -- it is all electromechanical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In unmanaged code you would listen for [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) in your top level windowproc.

That appears to be the only way to do it in managed code as well.